# Make Apache read PHP documents from RAM / Memory?

Tags: php, c++, apache

Is there any way to make Apache to read PHP documents from RAM?

I'm thinking of creating a virtual disk in the memory and then modify httpd.conf to change the document root directory to the virtual disk in the memory.

Is this viable?

Basically, what I want to do is distribute my PHP code to my users' computers so they can run it. But I don't want them to be able to look at the PHP source code easily - the code can't be stored in the harddisk in plain text, instead, they are stored in a data file and then read by my program into the memory where Apache reads it.

Is this viable? Is it easy to create a virtual disk in memory in C++ yet the virtual disk can't be accessed by any other means such as My Computer?

**Update:**

Thank you all for the questions which would help me better percept my goals, but I think I know what I'm doing. Please just suggest any solutions you may have towarding my needs.

The hard part thus far is for Apache to read from somewhere other than a plain directory in the harddisk that contains all the source code of my project. I would like it to be as concealed as possible. I know a little about windows desktop development and thought virtual disk might be a solution but if you have better ones, please suggest.

Comment: ... what? This seems bafflingly overcomplicated.

Comment: if you just want to protect the source code from the end users, use some obfustication.

Comment: @ceejayoz, it is. What I want is: deploy PHP+MySQL applications to desktop and the user can't peek at the source code of my PHP application.

Comment: Giving users the ability to run arbitrary code on your machine is a recipe for a disaster.

Comment: @Krishna, but the user can still copy and paste my source code into their own project. What I'm asking is not hardcore encryption, but the non-technical user can't easily find where my source code is.

Comment: @Charles, the code is run on their own computers.

Comment: Why do you want to use a web server stack for local applications? Why not host it on a server?

Comment: If your program can read the code, a determined user can read the code. Have them sign a contract and sue them if you steal your code.

Comment: @kavoir, if the code is *stored* on their machine, then *read* by your server, to be *served* to the user, then *your server* is executing the code from their computer.  That is dangerous.

Comment: At least use something like [ionCube](http://www.ioncube.com/) that was created for this purpose instead of creating your own Rube Goldberg machine.

Comment: @deceze, because server resources are expensive. However, client computers are idle 95% of the time.

Comment: @ceejayoz, as I said above, what I need is not hardcore encryption - it's not gonna work in experienced hands any way. If I can store my code in a single data file with simple encryption, I think it's enough to baffle 95% of the users from finding my code. But I just don't know how to read it there from Apache.

Comment: @deceze, thanks! That seems something great. I'll check it out and let you know.

Comment: [Zend Guard](http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/); [ionCube](http://www.ioncube.com/); [Source Guardian](http://www.sourceguardian.com/) - much more effective for this problem.  My company never deploy to an external server without such encryption.

Comment: In my experience, 100% of non-technical users are already sufficiently baffled by a .php file. ;)

Comment: @deceze: Though some of them can handle copy/paste.  Though that's a tad trickier if there's a database involved. ;-)

Comment: "@deceze, because server resources are expensive." Not really, no. Plenty of Fish serves over a billion pageviews a month off five servers. http://highscalability.com/plentyoffish-architecture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, in theory, have Apache serve files out of a Samba share.  You would need to configure the server to mount a specific file share made by the user.  This won't work if the user is behind a firewall or NAT gateway of any variety.

This will be:

- **Slower than molasses in January ... *in Alaska.***  Apache does a *lot* of `stat` calls on each request by default.  This is going to add a lot of overhead before even finding the file, transferring it over, and then executing it.
- **Hard to configure.** Adding mounts is a non-trivial task at the server level and Samba can be rather finicky on both sides.  Further, if you are using RHEL/CentOS or any other distro running SELinux, you're going to have to do the `chcon`/`setsebool` tapdance to even get it working.  The default settings expressly prohibit Apache from touching any file that came to the system through a Samba share.
- **A security nightmare.**  You will be allowing Apache to serve up files *to anyone* from a computer that is not under your direct control.  The malicious possibilities are endless.  This is a horrible idea that you should not seriously consider.

---

A safer-but-still-*insane* alternative might be available.  FastCGI.  The remote systems can run a FastCGI process and actually host and execute the code directly.  Apache can be configured to pass PHP requests to the remote FastCGI process.  This will still break if the users are firewalled or NATted.  This will only be an acceptable solution if the user can actually run a FastCGI process and you don't mind the code actually executing on *their* system instead of the server.

This has the distinct advantage of the files not *executing* in the context of the server.

---

Perhaps I've entirely misunderstood -- are you asking for code to be **run live from user's systems**?  Because I wrote this answer under that interpretation.